# How to access an embedding table that is too large to fully load into memory?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word-embeddings

I'm currently trying to find a way of loading/deserializing a .json file containing Flair word embeddings that is too large to fit in my RAM at once (>60GB .json with 32GB of RAM). My current code for loading the embedding is below.

```
def get_embedding_table(config):
    words_id2vec = json.load(open(config.words_id2vector_filename, 'r'))
    words_vectors = [0] * len(words_id2vec)
    for id, vec in words_id2vec.items():
        words_vectors[int(id)] = vec

    words_vectors.append(list(np.random.uniform(0, 1, config.embedding_dim)))
    words_embedding_table = tf.Variable(name='words_emb_table', initial_value=words_vectors, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The rest of the code that I am trying to reproduce with a different word embedding can be found [here](https://github.com/xiangrongzeng/copy_re).

I wonder if it is somehow possible to access the embedding table without deserialization of the entire .json file, for example: by sequentially reading it, somehow splitting it, or reading it directly from my disk. I would greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10715628/891919

Comment: @Erwan I've looked into this but I am not sure how I could make TensorFlow work with this approach. Do you maybe have an idea about this?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. I'm lucky enough to have access to a high performance cluster, so I don't have this kind of problem! If you're in academia you could maybe explore if there are any such resources you could use?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. Incrementally parse JSON with something like [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/). Munge and append each part to `tf.Variable`.
2. Reduce the precision of the numbers `dtype=tf.float32` to 
   `dtype=tf.bfloat16`

Comment: In case additional libraries are not an option, you can typically split a big JSON file in multiple small JSON files. This way, you could (lazily) load whatever part you need.